# Android: Change file-contents under /system/etc with Magisk

Tags: 8.1-oreo, magisk

I would like to change a configuration file under /system/etc or /etc. Neither of those locations are writeable and I can't make them writeable with a rw remount. The device is "rooted" with Magisk. 
How can this be done?

Comment: magisk is systemless root method. modifying system will break with all benefits magisk provides, and most likely trigger dm-verity protection. you should use bind mount overlays instead. however, on system-as-root devices you must remount rw `/` instead of `/system`